# Why are css selectors duplicated? (SCSS)

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I have one .scss file that is connected 4 times in other .scss files, why is the contents of this file 4 times included in the bundle.css? How to solve this problem?

**file_1.scss:**

```
.header_video_titles {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

**file_2.scss, file_3.scss, file_4.scss:**

```
@import "file_1.scss"
```

As a result, the bundle.css contains:

```
.header_video_titles {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.header_video_titles {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.header_video_titles {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
.header_video_titles {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Possibly [css-purge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-purge)? If webpacking, possibly [purge-css-loader](https://github.com/dzianisreznik/purge-css-loader)?

Comment: How it works for webpack?

Comment: Hmm, that loader looks like abandonware. Maybe [this one](https://github.com/americanexpress/purgecss-loader)?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you run an import, all css content is copied to the new file, as in the end all are compiled in 1, the original code is grouped with the others resulting in the repeated code.